# CSS - Two backgrounds?

Tags: html, css, vbulletin

I've got some code which I am running on my vBulletin system which sets a gradiented username colour based on two profile fields. However, I want to add sparkles to it, how do I go about it?

```
<span style="-webkit-text-fill-color:transparent; background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, COLOUR1), color-stop(1, COLOUR2)); background-size:0; text-shadow:none; -webkit-background-size:auto; -webkit-background-clip:text; font-weight:bold;">Forum Name</span>
```

How do I go about adding this sparkle code to the equiation?

```
  background: url(custom/v2/sparkles/sparkle-rainbow.gif) !important;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want the sparkling to fill the container that the text is in? Or do you want the text itself to sparkle? Can you edit the HTML or just the CSS?

Comment: I would like the text itself to Sparkle. Thanks @SwankyLegg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `url(custom/v2/sparkles/sparkle-rainbow.gif)` to the end of `background` part:

```
span{
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),  url(http://www.myspacehippo.com/files/glitterbacks/bg345.gif) repeat;
  background-size: 0;
  text-shadow: none;
  -webkit-background-size: auto;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

## In action

```css
span{
 font-size:100px;
 font-family:impact;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url(http://www.myspacehippo.com/files/glitterbacks/bg345.gif) repeat;
  text-shadow: none;
  -webkit-background-size: auto;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<span>This Text</span>
```